# Как и относительно чего считаются отступы, которые возникают при использовании flex-wrap: wrap?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Вот что я имею в виду:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 500px;
}

.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellowgreen;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-block">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

**Как, например, мне уменьшить этот отступ?**

Comment: Хм.... ща смотрю и во всех примерах они изначально прилеплены друг к другу -_-

Comment: Интересно даже стало -_-

Comment: Такс. А у тебя тут у них `margin: 5px` может он и задаёт этот отступ?

Comment: убрать фикс высоту родителя, можно просто внутренние отступы задать.

Comment: @DGDays ну как бы не должен, там получается явно больше 10px

Comment: @HamSter только что хотел откоментить ..с новым годом Лена

Comment: @MaximLensky, Спасибо! И тебя с Новым Годом! Успехов!

Comment: @MaximLensky с Новым годом:))))

Comment: @MaximLensky Ева:))) ... а почему на английском, если не секрет?

Comment: @MaximLensky а, понятно. Спасибо)

Comment: @Eva, я просто предположил) У меня на тлф как раз в 10px отступы

Comment: ВСЕХ С НОВЫМ ГОДОМ!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как уже было сказано в комментах, нужно убрать высоту у `flex-контейнера`. Либо явно указать выравнивание рядов по поперечной оси свойством `align-content` :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 500px;
}

.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellowgreen;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-block">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: не по середине же так

Comment: @HamSter , так вроде в вопросе по поводу середины ничего и не сказано. `align-content: center` и ряды будут выровнены по центру

Comment: Всё верно. А если кратко wrap равномерно распределяет слои на высоту родителя, тобеш если высота родителя - 500, высота каждого блока - 200 + марджин сверху и снизу у каждого по 5. Тогда расстояние между блоками равно 500 - 2*200 - 4*5 = 80px.

Comment: @GGO , ага. Вот только непонятно: почему `align-content: normal` (значение по умолчанию) работает как `align-content: space-around` ?

Comment: @zhurof, а с чего ты взял что они работают одинаково?

Comment: @GGO , попробовал несколько вариантов: в 2 ряда, 3, с разной высотой flex-элементов. `align-content: space-around` работало точно так же, как значение по умолчанию. Ни на пиксель не съехало